# Different categories and different grades of questions and answers

Tags: discussion, support, tags, site-scope, code-of-conduct

Are there different grades or categories of questions and answers posted on the main site and meta site? I have viewed very highly upvoted questions and answers. I guess some other questions and answers are media, some are less than medium. others are low-quality posts. I am suspended for low-quality posts very often on many sites. The recent suspension is on the "English language and usage" site. Are badges and reputations awarded on country or region wise?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think Europe, North America, South America, Australia, and Africa are mainly English speaking continents.
Citizens meaning users of these continents study high-standard English books. They are in a commanding position over Asians, especially over Indians.
They muddle along with the English language and the limit set for/by them is low. literally, Most players prefer a dead-draw position in a chess play with western country players.

Comment: This is just ignorant nonsense. India has 22 recognized regional languages (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_with_official_status_in_India). Furthermore "The business in Indian parliament can only be transacted in Hindi or in English. English is allowed to be used in official purposes such as parliamentary proceedings, judiciary, communications between the Central Government and a State Government."

Comment: @BrianTowers-I agree with you INDIA has 22 recognized regional languages. But do Indians play chess and interact in Indian languages? This is possible in INDIA to understand when they speak English. But it is hard to interact or have discussions in western countries In ENGLISH During a chess tournament. Not only chess tournaments, in other political or official conversations, how can we say INDIANS are better?Besides ENGLISH other languages and dialect differences are the causes. user-37920

Comment: @BrianTowers- What matters most is FIDE RULES effective from July 2017. and What the chess main site tags Verbal communication, nonverbal communication, and violent communications for? user-37920

Answer (score 3):

> my question is that are badges and reputations awarded on country or region wise?

No. It's purely based on the content and how the community votes on your posts. Stack Exchange is a global platform, there is no distinction between users from different countries. Of course, native English speakers may fare better (except on sites like [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)) but many [ESLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESL), including yours truly are holding their own on the network.

> Are there different grades or categories of questions and answers posted on the main site and meta site.

Well, Meta gets much fewer questions, but also fewer visits and hence less votes. Also, some questions on the main site have a very high number of views because they often appear in Google search results or were a [Hot Network Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/295232) for a certain amount of time.

> I am suspended for low-quality posts very often on many sites. My most recent suspension is on the "English Language & Usage" site.

That's sad, but we can't really help with this, other than pointing you at the FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232) You are not question banned on this site, FWIW, but you do have some deleted and negatively scoring posts, so please be careful.